# Add Customer data in custom module grid in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, grid

I have created a custom module in magento admin. In my module i have customer id.
Using this ID i want to show customer data in my custom module Grid. But i am not getting how to do it.

I have created grid using ui component.

[image]